# socket.getInetAddress() give Null Pointer Exception Android

Tags: android, sockets, nullpointerexception, server, udp

i've done a simple UDP chat p2p and when I tried it, it was all working right. Now that I've to do a report on this, I'm testing the project but I've NPE on the `socket.getInetAddress.getHostAddress()` and I can't understand why. 
Here the code:

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    byte[] lMsg = new byte[1024];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(lMsg, lMsg.length);
    DatagramSocket socket = null;

    try {

        while(true) {

            socket = new DatagramSocket(port);

            socket.receive(packet);

            ip = socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
            message = new String(lMsg, 0, packet.getLength());

            publishProgress();

            socket.close();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        String s = e.getLocalizedMessage();

    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            socket.close();
        }
    }
    return "Done";
}
```

The logcat tells me that the `socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()` generate a Null Pointer Exception. 
I tried to use `getLocalAddress()` to check if the problem is what I think and I'm right, but i can't understand how to fix it. I implemented the server UDP with `AsyncTask`.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Did you try emulator or real device?

Comment: I tried on real device